# Does there exist a method or plugin to allow for rotate transforms to respect div boundries?

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery-plugins

By default, the css rotate property seems to occur after tag spacing. [For instance, if you have two divs in a column and you rotate one, they overlap.](http://jsfiddle.net/ArielT/NKgCg/8/) It's possible I completely missed some aspect of css or html that handles this issue, have I?

The obvious solution seems to be to write some javascript to manage the placement of elements post rotate. Does a plugin exist that helps handle this spacing?  The only thing close I could locate was the [jquery-rotate plug](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-rotate/), but it does not seems to provide any functionality with regard to spacing.

Relevant html/css demonstrating the spacing problem.

HTML

```
<div class="red-box rotate-right"></div>
<div class="blue-box"></div>​
```

CSS

```
.rotate-right {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}

.red-box{
  height: 50px;
  width: 100px;
  background: red;
}

.blue-box{
  height: 50px;
  width: 100px;
  background: blue;
}
```

Comment: Use jquery .animate() and move the second div on y-axis when the first div is rotating.

Answer (score 2):

Alright, beware this is ugly to look at.

First, I used [code from CSS-Tricks](http://css-tricks.com/get-value-of-css-rotation-through-javascript/) to get the angle of rotation. Then, I use some algebra to find the distance (from the center of the rotated element) to the sides of a box that contains the element. Then I add margins to the edge of the rotated element to create (or remove) extra space where needed. This also takes into account the original margins (if any).

Usage:

After rotating an element, call `$(rotatedElement).space([grow],[shrink])`. See code comments for argument descriptions.

```
jQuery.fn.space = function(grow,shrink){
    // grow = Grow area around element to fit? (true/false)
    // shrink = Shrink area around element to fit? (true/false)
    var el = this.get(0);
    if(typeof(grow)=='undefined'){
        grow = true; // Default to grow extra space when needed
    }
    if(typeof(shrink)=='undefined'){
        shrink = false; // Default to not shrink at all
    }

    //Get angle of rotated element
    var st = window.getComputedStyle(el, null);
    var tr = st.getPropertyValue("-webkit-transform") ||
         st.getPropertyValue("-moz-transform") ||
         st.getPropertyValue("-ms-transform") ||
         st.getPropertyValue("-o-transform") ||
         st.getPropertyValue("transform");
    var v = tr.split('(')[1].split(')')[0].split(',');
    var scale = Math.sqrt(v[0]*v[0] + v[1]*v[1]);
    var angle = Math.round(Math.atan2(v[1], v[0]) * (180/Math.PI));

    //Save or recall original margins
    var m = new Array();
    if(el.getAttribute('margins')==null){
        m[0] = st.getPropertyValue("margin-left").match(/\d+/);
        m[1] = st.getPropertyValue("margin-right").match(/\d+/);
        m[2] = st.getPropertyValue("margin-top").match(/\d+/);
        m[3] = st.getPropertyValue("margin-bottom").match(/\d+/);
        el.setAttribute('margins',m[0]+","+m[1]+","+m[2]+","+m[3]);
    } else {
        m = el.getAttribute('margins').split(',');
        console.log(m);
    }
    //Get center coords
    var cx = st.getPropertyValue("width").match(/\d+/)/2;
    var cy = st.getPropertyValue("height").match(/\d+/)/2;

    //Convert radian values to degrees
    function toDeg(angle){
        return angle*Math.PI/180;
    }

    // Coords of the corners
    // (starting from top-left and proceeding clockwise)
    // relative to the center of the element
    // c[cornerID][x|y]
    var c = [ [Math.round(cx*Math.cos(toDeg(angle-180))
                 + cy*Math.cos(toDeg(angle-90))),
               Math.round(cx*Math.sin(toDeg(angle-180))
                 + cy*Math.sin(toDeg(angle-90)))],

              [Math.round(cx*Math.cos(toDeg(angle))
                 + cy*Math.cos(toDeg(angle-90))),
               Math.round(cx*Math.sin(toDeg(angle))
                 + cy*Math.sin(toDeg(angle-90)))],

              [Math.round(cx*Math.cos(toDeg(angle))
                 + cy*Math.cos(toDeg(angle+90))),
               Math.round(cx*Math.sin(toDeg(angle))
                 + cy*Math.sin(toDeg(angle+90)))],

              [Math.round(cx*Math.cos(toDeg(angle-180))
                 + cy*Math.cos(toDeg(angle+90))),
               Math.round(cx*Math.sin(toDeg(angle-180))
                 + cy*Math.sin(toDeg(angle+90)))]
            ];

    var elx = ([c[0][0], c[1][0], c[2][0], c[3][0]]).sort(function(a,b){
                                                          return(a*1)-(b*1);});
    var ely = ([c[0][1], c[1][1], c[2][1], c[3][1]]).sort(function(a,b){
                                                          return(a*1)-(b*1);});

    var b = [-elx[0], elx[3], -ely[0], ely[3]]; // [Left, Right, Top, Bottom]

    if(grow){
        if(b[0]-cx>0) el.style.marginLeft = (m[0] + b[0]-cx) + "px";
        if(b[1]-cx>0) el.style.marginRight = (m[1] + b[1]-cx) + "px";
    /*}
    if(growY){ */
        if(b[2]-cy>0) el.style.marginTop = (m[2] + b[2]-cy) + "px";
        if(b[3]-cy>0) el.style.marginBottom = (m[3] + b[3]-cy) + "px";
    }
    if(shrink){
        if(b[0]-cx<0) el.style.marginLeft = (m[0] + b[0]-cx) + "px";
        if(b[1]-cx<0) el.style.marginRight = (m[1] + b[1]-cx) + "px";
    /*}
    if(shrinkY){ */
        if(b[2]-cy<0) el.style.marginTop = (m[2] + b[2]-cy) + "px";
        if(b[3]-cy<0) el.style.marginBottom = (m[3] + b[3]-cy) + "px";
    }

}
```

You may wish to split (`grow` and `shrink`) into (`growX`, `growY` and `shrinkX`, `shrinkY`) depending on what's going on in your live site, so you don't break your layout. To do so, just adjust/add the arguments and defaults at the top, and the `if(grow)`/`if(shrink)` statements at the bottom.